# iOS - Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'Float'

Tags: ios, swift, constants

I have trouble with variable types to declare and use constants.

```
let MAX_RADIUS_IN_MILE = 100.0

radiusSlider.maximumValue = MAX_RADIUS_IN_MILE
```

In this case, I get an error - `Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'Float'`

I don't want to declare a constant with a type definition like this `let MAX_RADIUS_IN_MILE: Float = 100.0` but just wanna know another smart way to do make this constant as Float.

Any idea?

For example, C# has a solution for this.

Comment: You don't want strong typing, but you want strong typing. Hmm...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "professional".  There may be a loss of precision when converting between `Float` and `Double`, so the compiler won't allow an implicit cast. You have to show you know what you are doing by using an explicit type or conversion.

Comment: *just wanna know another smart way to do make this constant as Float* Use `as Float` like this:  `let MAX_RADIUS_IN_MILE = 100 as Float`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use camelCase for naming in Swift. lowerCamelCase for constants/variables/functions and UpperCamelCase for types (classes, ...)

> `MAX_RADIUS_IN_MILE -> maxRadiusInMile`

---

Now to your problem. Error is clear, you have constant of type `Double` (if you don't specify type of decimal number, compiler give it type `Double`), but assigning `maximumValue` requires type `Float`. What now?

One solution if you need your constant to be of type `Float` is: specify type of your constant as `Float`

```
let maxRadiusInMile: Float = 100
let maxRadiusInMile = Float(100)
```

Anyway, if you need this constant just for assigning one value, use can assign it directly

```
radiusSlider.maximumValue = 100
```

---

If you from some reason need your constant to be of type `Double`, then you can convert your constant of type `Double` to `Float` using designed initializer

```
let maxRadiusInMile = 100.0
radiusSlider.maximumValue = Float(maxRadiusInMile)
```